# Compare via pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I would like some explanation as to what a part of this function does:

```
bool Compare(CBox* pBox) const
    {
        if (!pBox)
            return 0;
        return this->Volume() > pBox->Volume();
    }
```

What does if(!pBox) check for? Is that if statement necessary?

Comment: What if `pBox` is null?

Comment: As a side note: The code also should check for `pBox == this` and return `true` for this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if (!pBox)` checks if the pointer `pBox` is null. It is necessary since you are calling a function (`Volume()`).

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense. I'm not sure why I forgot about null checks.

Answer (score 2):

The IF is testing for null, if it is true (not zero), it ensure a zero being returned. It is necessary since you are comparing an instantiated object (you are calling its method) against another and this last can be null.